# python set random seed, but results not reusing

Tags: python, machine-learning, random, random-seed

I'm training a simple neural network model in python, I need to run batch experiments to test the performance of different module configurations by executing `python train.py`.

**train configs**:

1. dataset_A, dataset_B, dataset_C, total 3 datasets
2. total 19 model configurations.

**Python training mode**:

1. if I using 2 for loops to generate some results, some of them are wrong. If I rerun the wrong results seperately, the correct results will be produced, even if run multiple times.
2. I split the 3 datasets, modify the `train.py` and run it one dataset at a time, I get different results than in training mode 1).

I set the random seed in the `./utils/util.py`:

```py
def set_seed(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
```

In `train.py`, it calls the function `set_seed(42)`. In short, if I set exact same configuration, multiple runs will produce the same results. However, if I just change the order of the datasets list, I will have different results. I would be grateful if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: Please provide the full code of your experiment in train.py

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.